# Create array of certain attribute from a list of elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have some of divs.

```
<div data-id="1"></div>
<div data-id="2"></div>
<div data-id="3"></div>
<div data-id="4"></div>
```

Is there a way to get an array of the `data-id` attribute: `["1", "2", "3", "4"]` without using `.each`?

Comment: You can use a for-loop, not sure if you're including that in the "without using .each" part or not.

Comment: regardless of whatever method you use it will require looping over the elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/): [**(example here)**](http://jsfiddle.net/mz72p1rd/)

```
var array = $('div[data-id]').map(function(){
    return $(this).data('id');
}).get();

console.log(array);
```

---

Alternatively, using pure JS: [**(example here)**](http://jsfiddle.net/qgbt4gt0/)

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-id]'),
    array = [];

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el){
    array.push(parseInt(el.dataset.id, 10));
});

console.log(array);
```

...or using a regular for-loop: [**(example here)**](http://jsfiddle.net/qpvdrjh8/)

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-id]'),
    array = [],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
    array.push(parseInt(elements[i].dataset.id, 10));
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Nice. Do you know anything about the efficiency of map vs. a loop?

Comment: loop will *always* be faster, but if you're not going through thousands of elements, it's not gonna matter

Answer (score 2):

You could use a for loop and do it without JQuery even, in case you are looking for a more primitive solution, like:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id]');
for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
   // do something here with nodes[i]
}
```

Or to optain an array directly from your query result you could also use `Array.prototype.map.call`:

```
var values = Array.prototype.map.call(nodes, function(e){ return e.dataset.id; });
```

Answer (score 0):

`var array=$('div[data-id]');//array` will store all the div containing `data-id` in the order as it is appearing in your DOM.

so suppose you want to get 2nd div just do like this `array[1].attr('id')`